# pr2_robot source on kforge or github?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pr2_robot stack page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_robot) links to [kforge/pr2_robot](https://kforge.ros.org/pr2robot/hg) for the sources, for every distro, but it states new issues should be reported on [github/pr2_robot](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_robot/issues). As there also is the full and newer (?) source, and with the general move to github in mind, I'm confused if the source link is correct and to be used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59896/pr2_robot-source-on-kforge-or-github?/) by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pr2 github organization and repositories were created after the groovy release, so groovy debians are being built from kforge. However, I presume that hydro releases will come from the new github repositories.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-30**:
And patches seem to be welcome on github.